# Running QML or Qt on iOS

Tags: ios, qt, qml, lighthouse

We've searched the net for this matter but couldn't find a proper answer.

It is known that lighthouse project is for porting Qt programs to IOS but there's no documentation about using it or compiling it on Mac. Any suggestions in this matter?

There's another work in progress the project qt-iphone which while compiling in mac we get the error "  it seems that you dont have "make" or "gmake"  " and we couldn't find the solution on the net about fixing it.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.mediator-software.com/

The latest sdk just released couple of days ago, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Qt now supports this [natively](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ios-support.html) starting with Qt 5.2.